# Need to send the web service request contentiously till get response using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My requirement is as follows:

1. I will be copying one test data file to one location. [My application will pick file, process it and will respond using web service]
2. So when I login to my application and go to that page, every 5 seconds web service request would be sent.

Above two, i can handle using JMeter. Now next is

3. Need to send the web service request contentiously [maybe each request in 5 seconds] till get response using JMeter

So how can I do this?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

- [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) with condition depending on the response

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler

    - [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to sleep for 5 seconds
    - Maybe a [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to set the While Controller's condition

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more details on implementing [while loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) in JMeter tests.